# How to tell if mouse moved during .click()?

Tags: jquery

According to the jQuery documentation for [.click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/), the event is triggered only after this series of events:

- The mouse button is depressed while the pointer is inside the element.
- The mouse button is released while the pointer is inside the element.

The problem I'm facing is that I'm using "click to drag" functionality on a grid of items, each of which I'd like to register the click event for. This means each time I click to drag, the mouse is pressed on an item, then released on that same item after the drag has occurred.  This fires the click event.

Is there any way to only fire the event if the mouse has not moved between when the mouse has been depressed to when the mouse has been released?  Though this seems trivial, as a jQuery beginner I'm sort of stumped.

Comment: if the mouse button is depressed, give him some xanax!

Comment: on mousedown record mouse position, then on click compare it. Or, implement a drag event into your drag functionality so that you can set a flag within it, then unset it after x ms (10 should be enough to allow click event to happen before it gets unset)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Keep track of the mouse position between mousedown and mouseup to see it the mouse pointer moved. You should probably add a little margin of error, like a few pixels every way, but below is a simplified example :

```
var left  = 0,
    top   = 0;    

$(element).on({
    mousedown: function(e) {
        left  = e.pageX;
        top   = e.pageY;
    },
    mouseup: function(e) {
        if (left != e.pageX || top != e.pageY) {
            alert(' OMG, it moved ! ');
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I modified @adeneo's code a little bit, so it takes care of the problem where the user moves the cursor "just a little bit" and it should actually be interpreted as a click. I used eucledian distance for this. You could drop the `Math.sqrt` for better performance, but then you have to adjust the `radiusLimit` variable.

```
var left = 0,
    top = 0,
    radiusLimit = 5;

$(element).on({
  mousedown: function(event) {
    left = event.pageX;
    top = event.pageY;
  },
  mouseup: function(event) {
    var deltaX = event.pageX - left;
    var deltaY = event.pageY - top;
    var euclidean = Math.sqrt(deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY);

    if (euclidean < radiusLimit) {
      console.log("this is a click.");
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you consider a mousedown and a mouseup event trigger to be a viable alternative? If the coordinates of the mousedown are the same as the coordinates for the mouseup, the cursor has not changed position during the click.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such event, as that would be almost completely useless. It's very common that the mouse moves slightly while clicking even if the user didn't intend that, especially with a regular mouse where the button for clicking is located on the moused itself.

Get the mouse coordinates in the mousedown and mouseup events, and act on the mouseup event depending on how far the mouse has moved.