# How to not trigger the onClick event when Clicking for copy and pasting?

Tags: javascript, onclick, dom-events, copy-paste

I have a link with an `onClick` event that make me navigate to a different page.
However when the user click and stay clicked to select part of the text of the link to copy it to clipboard, I do not want to trigger the `onClick` event.

Is there a way to differentiate instant Click, from prolonged Click?

Comment: Yes, use the mousedown, mouseup and event locations to know if the user moved the mouse while clicking, you can then `preventDefault`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/31313910/227299

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jQuery for simplicity only. Logic will be the same for [vanilla JavaScript](http://vanilla-js.com/). Most code is from https://stackoverflow.com/a/31313910/227299. The only difference from that answer is that you have to use that knowledge to decide whether to call `preventDefault()`

```js
var left = 0,
  top = 0,
  radiusLimit = 5,
  didMove = false;

$('a').on({
  mousedown: function(event) {
    left = event.pageX;
    top = event.pageY;
  },
  mouseup: function(event) {
    var deltaX = event.pageX - left;
    var deltaY = event.pageY - top;
    var euclidean = Math.sqrt(deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY);

    didMove = euclidean > radiusLimit;
  },
  click: function(e) {
    if (didMove) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://google.com">Here is a link that we can select half the text</a>
```